# Integration of $e^{ax}\cos bx$ and $e^{ax}\sin bx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am curious about the proof of these two integrations. It would be great if you could point me in the right direction :

$
\int{e^{ax}\cos({bx})dx}= \dfrac{e^{ax}}{a^{2}+b^{2}}[a\cos(bx)+b\sin(bx)] + C
$

&

$
\int{e^{ax}\sin({bx})dx}= \dfrac{e^{ax}}{a^{2}+b^{2}}[a\sin(bx)-b\cos(bx)] + C
$

Comment: Try using integration by parts twice on either one of these. You should get the same integral back on the RHS; collect terms and simplify.

Comment: Thank you.I tried but didn't reach the same result,maybe I did some mistake. Can you leave an answer of your solution?

Comment: Why don't you post what you tried so we can figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: Now that I'm looking to scam00's answer,I can see that I had so many mistakes.

Comment: You need $+C$ at the end of both integrals.

Comment: Are you sure about $+C$. Why is that useful?

Comment: Your second equation should have "$-$" instead of "$+$" separating the terms inside the brackets on the right side. See my answer below.

Comment: @sajjad It's not because it's "useful", it's because it's required by the definition of indefinite integrals.

Comment: If all you want is a proof, just take the derivative of the right-hand side...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integrate by parts.

$$I=\int e^{ax}\cos (bx)\, dx=\left(e^{ax}\right)\left(\frac{\sin(bx)}{b}\right)-\int \left(ae^{ax}\right)\left(\frac{\sin(bx)}{b}\right)\, dx$$

$$=\left(e^{ax}\right)\left(\frac{\sin(bx)}{b}\right)-\frac{a}{b}\int \left(e^{ax}\right)(\sin (bx)\, dx)$$

$$=\left(e^{ax}\right)\left(\frac{\sin(bx)}{b}\right)-\frac{a}{b}\left(\left(e^{ax}\right)\left(\frac{\cos(bx)}{-b}\right)-\int \left(ae^{ax}\right)\left(\frac{\cos(bx)}{-b}\right)\, dx\right)$$

$$=\left(e^{ax}\right)\left(\frac{\sin(bx)}{b}\right)-\frac{a}{b}\left(e^{ax}\right)\left(\frac{\cos(bx)}{-b}\right)-\frac{a^2}{b^2}I$$

Solve for I:

$$I=\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{e^{ax}\sin(bx)}{b}+\frac{ae^{ax}\cos(bx)}{b^2}\right)+C$$

$$=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left(b\sin(bx)+a\cos(bx)\right)+C$$

Now find $\int e^{ax}\sin(bx)\, dx$ in an analogous way.

Answer (score 13):

By far the easiest way to prove this is to write (omitting the arbitrary constant of integration)
$$\int e^{ax}\cos bx\;dx + i\int e^{ax}\sin bx\;dx = \int e^{ax}(\cos bx + i\sin bx)\;dx = \int e^{(a+bi)x}\;dx$$
$$=\frac1{a+bi}e^{(a+bi)x} =\frac{a-bi}{a-bi}\cdot\frac1{a+bi}e^{(a+bi)x}=\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}e^{(a+bi)x}$$
$$=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}(a-bi)(\cos bx + i\sin bx)$$
$$=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\big[(a\cos bx+b\sin bx) + i(a\sin bx - b\cos bx)]$$
$$=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}(a\cos bx+b\sin bx) + i\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}(a\sin bx - b\cos bx)$$

Equating real parts, and equating imaginary parts, we obtain

$$\boxed{\int e^{ax}\cos bx\;dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}(a\cos bx+b\sin bx)}$$
$$\boxed{\int e^{ax}\sin bx\;dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}(a\sin bx - b\cos bx)}$$
as desired.

The essential part of this, and the part to remember, is simply that
$\int e^{(a+bi)x}\;dx = \frac1{a+bi}e^{(a+bi)x}$.

Answer (score 1):

An hint: $cos(bx)=\frac{e^{ibx}+e^{-ibx}}{2}$