# A problem with integration with trigonometric equations and indices.

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

Consider this integral:

$$\int e^x\cdot cos(x)\space dx$$

Using integration by parts: $\int uv'\space dx=uv- \int u'v \space dx$

I have 2 possible outcomes:

1.) Using $u=e^x$, $v'=cos (x)$, $u'=e^x$ and $v=sin(x)$ gives:
$$\int e^x\cdot cos(x)\space dx=e^x\cdot cos(x)-\int e^x\cdot sin(x)\space dx$$

2.) Using $u=cos (x)$, $v'=e^x (x)$, $u'=-sin(x)$ and $v=e^x$ gives:

$$\int e^x\cdot cos(x)\space dx=e^x\cdot cos(x)-\int -e^x\cdot sin(x)\space dx$$

$$\int e^x\cdot cos(x)\space dx=e^x\cdot cos(x)+\int e^x\cdot sin(x)\space dx$$

So I get:

$$e^x\cdot cos(x)-\int e^x\cdot sin(x)\space dx=e^x\cdot cos(x)+\int e^x\cdot sin(x)\space dx$$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502055/integration-of-eax-cos-bx-and-eax-sin-bx

Comment: It is different. Mine is only $e^x$

Comment: What if $a=b=1$?

Comment: Yes. I am in confusion as to where have I or this equation have gone wrong.

Comment: In 1.) your first term "$uv$" should be $e^x\sin x$, not $e^x\cos x$.

Comment: Ahhhh I see now I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if there is a name for this.

We have
\begin{align*}
\int e^x\cos x\,dx&=e^{x}\sin x-\int e^{x}\sin x\,dx\tag 1\\
&=e^{x}\sin x-\left[-e^x\cos x-\int- e^x\cos x\,dx+C\right]\tag 2\\
&=e^x\sin x+e^x\cos x-\int e^x\cos x\,dx+C.
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$ I let $u = e^x, dv = \cos x$, and in $(2)$ I let $u = e^x, dv = \sin x$.
Then adding $\int e^x\cos x\,dx$ to both sides and solving gives
$$\int e^x\cos x\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\big[e^x\sin x+e^x\cos x+C\big].$$

Comment: Is there a name for this? When it's $e^{-x}$ it's called a damped sinusoidal. Picture the graph of $y=\cos x$ squeezed between the graphs of $y=e^{-x}$ and $y=-e^{-x}$.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, I see that. But I meant, when we have these "cyclic" integrals that return to itself.

Comment: The same technique can be used to integrate $e^{ax}\cos(bx)$ or $e^{ax}\sin(bx)$ to get a general formula for this type of integral.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: I have never heard of a name for it. I always taught my students to do integration by parts by the tabular method and told them to keep going until they could integrate the bottom row of the table or until the bottom row was a multiple (other than 1) of the original integrand.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the tabular technique. Just like the damped sinusoidal, I wouldn't be surprised if the trait of being "cyclic" has a name.