# Integration By Parts (Continuos maths)

Tags: integration

Use integration by parts to calculate  =   f  e^(ax) cos   for  ≠ 0 and  ≠ 0.

This is my working so far. The part where i have to integrate is confusing so with some help maybe i can do it .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCRn1.jpg)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502055/integration-of-eax-cos-bx-and-eax-sin-bx

Comment: so is there like 2 possible answers ? I am so sorry but i am trying to follow the method taught by our school and it will be great if u can tell me how to work on the second part

Comment: For example, the derivative of $e^{ax}$ is $ae^{ax}$, not $e^{ax}$.  Similarly your integral of $\cos(bx)$ is wrong.