# Integration by Substitution of $\cos(\log(x))$

Tags: integration, substitution

I need to find the indefinite integral:
$\int \cos(\log(x)) dx$.

I've tried using u-substitution, setting $u=\log(x)$.  Then I get:
$\int \cos(u)du$, where $du$ is $\frac{1}{x}dx$.

The worked solutions I can see put an $e^u$ in there as well, and I'm not really sure why.  How should I go about solving this problem?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\ln x=u\implies x=e^u,dx=e^u\ du$

$$\int\cos(\ln x)dx=\int e^u\cos u\ du $$

Now use [Integration of $e^{ax}\cos bx$ and $e^{ax}\sin bx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502055/integration-of-eax-cos-bx-and-eax-sin-bx)

**See also** : Set $n=-1$ in [$100$-th derivative of the function $f(x)=e^{x}\cos(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752455/100-th-derivative-of-the-function-fx-ex-cosx/1752462#1752462)

Comment: How do you know that $dx=e^u du$?

Comment: @ThreeOneFour, $$du=\dfrac{dx}x=\dfrac{dx}{e^u}$$ right?

Answer (score 1):

Better way:

Recall that $$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$$
So  $$\cos \log x=\frac{e^{i\log x}+e^{-i\log x}}2=\frac{x^i+x^{-i}}2$$
And hence 
$$\int\cos\log x\,\mathrm dx=\frac12\left[\frac1{1+i}x^{1+i}+\frac{1}{1-i}x^{1-i}\right]+C$$
Then using $$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
We have that $$\int\cos\log x\,\mathrm dx=\frac{x}2[\cos\log x+\sin\log x]+C$$